# DropDownList Selected Value is Set to "null" in the Model on POST action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

I wish to utilize the ASP.NET MVC convention to parse POSTed form submission to a model by `ActionResult MyAction(MyModel submitted)`. `MyModel` includes a property of the type that I defined -`UsState`-.
`submitted.UsState` as the result of the action returns `null`.

Is there any way to get the submitted to be set to proper value?

I have the following view with a form in a `MyForm.cshtml`

```
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, ...))
{
  @Html.DropDownList("States", 
    null, 
    new { @id = "state", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "State"})
}
...
```

with the controller

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyForm()
    {
        ViewBag.States = GetStatesList();
    }

    public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel info) //info.State is set to null on POST
    {
        return View();
    }
    private static List<SelectListItem> GetStatesList()
    {
        var states = new List<SelectListItem>();
        states.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "", Selected = true, Text = "State" });
        foreach (var s in UsStates.ToList())
        {
            var state = new SelectListItem { Value = s.Abbreviation, Text = s.Name, Disabled = !s.Available };
            states.Add(state);
        }
        return states;
    }

}
```

with the model

```
public class MyModel
{
    public UsState States { get; set; } //Do I need proper setter for it to work? 
}
public static class UsStates  //Should I get the UsStates in a different way? 
{
    private static List<UsState> states = new List<UsState> {
        new UsState("AL", "Alabama"),
        //...
    }
    public static List<UsState> ToList()
    { return states; }
}

public class UsState
{
    public UsState(string ab, string name, bool available = true)
    {
        Name = name;
        Abbreviation = ab;
        Available = available;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change you MyModel to

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string SelectedState {get;set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> States { get; set; }  
}
```

modify your view to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, ...))
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedState, Model.States, "State", 
    new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

I changed this to a DropDownListFor, because it will automatically generate the id and name attributes for you.  It will also create an element at the top "State" so that you don't have to pre-pend it to your list.

I removed your placeholder because placeholders are not supported with select elements.  As well as not to be used as replacements for labels.

Per W3C

> The placeholder attribute specifies a short hint that describes the
>   expected value of an input field (e.g. a sample value or a short
>   description of the expected format).

Split your controller actions to a GET/POST pair

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    //Get
        public ActionResult MyAction()
        {
            return View(new MyModel { States = GetStateList() });
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                model.States = GetStateList();
                return View(model);
            }

            //do whatever you are going to do with the posted information.

            return RedirectToAction("<some view>");  //redirect after a post usually to Index.
        }

        private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetStatesList()
        {
            var states = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (var s in UsStates.ToList())
            {
                var state = new SelectListItem { Value = s.Abbreviation, Text = s.Name, Disabled = !s.Available };
                states.Add(state);
            }
            return states;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume `public UsState States` in the revised model needs to be `List<UsState>` or `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` type, correct? 
Previously, the `States` in the view reffered to `ViewBag.States`, not `MyModel.States`

Comment: Thank you very much for your advise on the placeholder attribute. I was not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Note it should be `model.States = GetStateList(); return View(model)` in the POST method if `ModelState` is invalid

Comment: After Post, dropdown items disappear. is it something wrong with my code? or the solution has some problems?

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the POSTed data, I realized that the submitted form data -`States=AL`-type is `string`, which would fail to be set as `UsState` type.

I changed the model to the following:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string States { get; set; }
}
```

I get the string value of the submitted form, at least. Not sure if this is given - if that's the case, I suppose I should use a separate `ViewModel` in order to get `States` as a string, and convert that into `MyModel` where I cast `string States` into `UsState States`.